# Javascript .replace fails on specific server

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with some Javascript which seems to work fine on my laptop when connected to localhost but not when the code is placed on a remote server and I connect to that from the same laptop and browser (IE11). The relevant code snippet is:

```
      var wktxt = inputs[i].getAttribute( "ondblClick" );
      wktxt = wktxt.replace("(" + rowno,  "(" + rowcnt)
      inputs[i].setAttribute( "ondblClick", wktxt );
      inputs[i].style.backgroundImage = "url()";
```

It fails on the second line with "Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'" yet the problem is not hit locally and behaves precisely as intended (this is part of some logic that clones a row within an HTML table). When I initiate debugging on the failure, wktxt contains "function ondblclick() {AddNotes2(1,0) }", rowno is 1 and rowcnt is 7.

Any ideas? This code is executed within a loop - could it be anything to do with the var declaration being re-executed on each iteration?

Comment: How come you do `replace` on a funcion? Or it is just a sting containing that function's declaration. Could you try to console.log `typeof wktxt` right after you assign value to it?

Comment: are you sure that `inputs[i]` have this attribute `"ondblClick"`?

Comment: I am a bit of a Javascript novice but all I am trying to replace are the parameters being passed to the function - i.e. AddNotes2(1,0) becomes AddNotes2(7,0). Presumably, if wktxt does contain text on debug then this implies that the attribute is present. This code only executes for a specific quantity field that should have the attribute.

Comment: as say [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) _Essentially all web browsers (Firefox, Internet Explorer, recent versions of Opera, Safari, Konqueror, and iCab, as a non-exhaustive list) return null when the specified attribute does not exist on the specified element_ so i think this input simply don't have this attribute

Answer (score 0):

Since the replace method is part of the string object prototype. It would seem that the result of your var wktxt may not always equal a string. To test this you can use the typof statement. Something like

```
if (typeof wktxt === 'string') {
    wktxt = wktxt.replace("(" + rowno,  "(" + rowcnt)
    inputs[i].setAttribute( "ondblClick", wktxt );
    inputs[i].style.backgroundImage = "url()";
}
else {
    //write some code here to put whatever you want in wktxt should it fail to evaluate to
    // a string
}
```

Comment: The typeof is 'string' when running on one server and 'function' on the other. Any idea why this might be happening?